# Don't know how handle keyboard two if judgment in pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

My problem is the keyboard will appear when users use the command /menu

And the user enters the content in the keyboard, it uses the if condition to check whether the user has typed the text I specified

If so, go to the next keyboard , and then check if the user has typed the text I specified

I want the user to use the command to determine whether his text was entered correctly.

Now if the user does not turn on the keyboard but enters the correct text, the text in the condition can be displayed.

How can I solve this problem?

I hope the effect is as follows (code is not working)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def menu(message):
   main_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   main_keyboard.row('OS System','WebSite')
   bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what you want to see?", reply_markup=main_keyboard)
   if message.text =="OS System":
       os_system_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
       os_system_keyboard.row('Linux','Windows')
       bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what os you want to see?", reply_markup=os_system_keyboard)
       if message.text =="Liunx":
           bot.send_message(message,"Linux distros : Ubuntu,LiunxMint....")
       elif message.text =="Windows":
           bot.send_message(message,"Windows distros : windows7 windows xp...")
   elif message.text =="WebSite":
       website_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
       website_keyboard.row('Videos','Knowledge')
       bot.send_message(message,"What type website you want to know ?")
       if message.text =="Videos":
           bot.send_message(message,"Youtube, Netfilx")
       elif message.text =="Knowledge":
           bot.send_message(message,"wiki...")
   else:
       bot.send_message(message,"The text you have entered has no relevant content,Please try again.")
```

i dont want to like this :

```
def main_menu(msg):                     #(row_width=4)
    main_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    main_keyboard.row('OS System','WebSite')
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what you want to see?", reply_markup=main_keyboard)

def os_menu(msg):
    os_system_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    os_system_keyboard.row('Linux','Windows')
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what os you want to see?", reply_markup=os_system_keyboard)

def web_menu(msg):
    web_keyborad = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    os_system_keyboard.row('Videos','Knowledge')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def menu(message):
    main_menu(message)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    if message.text =="OS System":
        main_keyboard(message)
    elif message.text =="WebSite":
        web_keyborad(message)
    elif message.text =="Linux":
        bot.send_message(message,"Linux distros : Ubuntu,LiunxMint....")
    elif message.text =="Windows"
        bot.send_message(message,"Windows distros : windows7 windows xp...")
    elif message.text =="Videos":
        bot.send_message(message,"Youtube, Netfilx")
    elif message.text =="Knowledge":
        bot.send_message(message,"wiki...")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message,"The text you have entered has no relevant content,Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code doesn't work because `msg.chat.id` is always the same and doesn't change every time (it's a simple variable). You can fix that problem using the `next_step_handler()` method; here is some code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def menu(message):
    main_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    main_keyboard.row('OS System','WebSite')
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what you want to see?", reply_markup=main_keyboard)
    bot.next_step_handler(msg, options)

def options(message):
    if message.text =="OS System":
        os_system_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        os_system_keyboard.row('Linux','Windows')
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="what os you want to see?", reply_markup=os_system_keyboard)
        bot.next_step_handler(msg, osSistem)
    elif message.text =="WebSite":
        website_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        website_keyboard.row('Videos','Knowledge')
        msg = bot.send_message(message,"What type website you want to know ?")
        bot.next_step_handler(msg, website)

def osSistem(message):
    if message.text =="Liunx":
        bot.send_message(message,"Linux distros : Ubuntu,LiunxMint....")
    elif message.text =="Windows":
        bot.send_message(message,"Windows distros : windows7 windows xp...")

def website(message):
    if message.text =="Videos":
        bot.send_message(message,"Youtube, Netfilx")
    elif message.text =="Knowledge":
        bot.send_message(message,"wiki...")
```

With this `next_step_handler`, you can pass a message, and a function, and python will start that function taking as `message` the new input (a keyboard is not required).